# Calculator in Swift Course crash

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p

I'm trying to follow a course on Swift by Stanford on iTunes U but I got stuck when it came to creating the enter key. As soon as I press the enter key in the simulator the app crashes and gives me no description of why. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var display: UILabel!

var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = false

@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber == false {
        display.text = digit
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = true
    } else {
    display.text = display.text! + digit
    }


}


var operandStack = Array<Double>()

@IBAction func enter() {
    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = false
    operandStack.append(displayValue)
    print("operandStack = \(operandStack)")
}

var displayValue: Double {
    get {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    } set {
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = false
    }
}
```

}

Comment: See the following to learn how to debug a crash: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Check if you get any value in the 'displayValue' if it's nil it will crash at append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my first app that I worked on too! This happens to me all the time. What probably happened is you are getting a SIGABRT because the function from the button has been changed or has a bad reference. A simple way to fix this is like so:

1. Click on the button that is causing the program to crash in the storyboard
2. Go to the Show Connections Inspector (Blue arrow with a circle *See picture)
3. Click the black x in the Connections inspector (it should show up like this in the picture, my connection is blurEffect).

[image: Show Connections Inspector]

4. Go back to the view controller and comment out or delete the reference to the old button connections (There should be a black dot by the function to say that there is a missing connection).
5. Try relinking the function button back to the code and put the old code back in the function.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you!! It finally works and I can now go on with the course!